# « Autant » ou « aussi » ?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, adverbes

Dans quels cas doit-on utiliser l'un plutôt que l'autre, et vice versa ?

Par exemple, est-il correct de dire :

> Ils sont aussi populaires les uns que les autres.

Ou cette forme-ci est-elle plus appropriée ?

> Ils sont autant populaires les uns que les autres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;PL** : **On peut échanger *autant* et *aussi* seulement quand il s'agit de comparaison d'adjectifs attributs**, sauf dans certains cas particuliers et dans ce cas *aussi* est plus courant. Par exemple « Ils sont autant populaires les uns que les autres. » n'est pas correct¹ : *autant* ne peut pas précéder immédiatement un adjectif.

Dans les autres cas de comparaison, *autant* s'emploie surtout pour une proposition, façon « on y mange *autant* qu'on y boit », alors que *aussi* s'emploie pour un adverbe « aussi méchamment que ». Dans des emplois où il ne s'agit pas de comparaison, la confusion est plus difficile.

Le détails du [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aussi) sur les cas particuliers en question :

> I.− [Porte sur un adj. ou un autre adv., ou modifie une loc. verbale]
>   A.− Il signifie la comparaison d'égalité […]
>   1. Aussi… que
>   a) [Porte sur un adj. et **dans ce cas si la prop. est affirmative, peut commuter avec autant**] :
>   […]
>   Rem. 1. **La commutation avec autant n'est pas possible dans le tour aussi … que si** <sup>[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aussi)</sup>

Et dans [autant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/autant)

> I.− Adv. de compar. exprimant en phrase compar., explicite ou implicite, l'égalité de deux procès, quant à leur intensité, leur quantité ou leur valeur.
>   A.− Autant est suivi d'une prop. complétive, d'un terme de compar. introd. par le corrélatif que.
>   1. [La compar. est explicite.]  […]
>   b) Rare. [La prop. princ. est attributive]
>   − [Sans ell. dans la sub. compar.] : 
>   […]
>   Rem. **On emploie plus fréquemment le tour est aussi + adj. … que**.
>   […]
>   − **Autant ne peut précéder immédiatement l'adj.** : *Elle était autant pieuse que personne, mais on dit : Elle était pieuse autant que personne.
>   − **Autant ne peut modifier l'adj. épithète ou apposé**; mais cet emploi, possible au XVII<sup>e</sup>s. survit sporadiquement […]

---

1. Comme d'habitude, pour une certaine valeur de *correct*. Ici c'est *en français standard*.