# "autant" ou "aussi bien" pour modifier un verbe

Tags: verbes, comparatifs

> J'aime la physique **autant que** la chimie.
>
> J'aime la physique **aussi bien que** la chimie.

Quelle phrase est correcte ? Ou les deux phrases sont correctes mais ont des significations différentes ?

(J'ai lu [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5953/autant-ou-aussi) sur la différence entre "autant" et "aussi", mais là il s'agit d'une modification d'un adjectif, tandis qu'ici on veut modifier le verbe "aimer".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les deux phrases sont correctes avec des sens différents.

> J'aime la physique autant que la chimie.

veut dire que j'aime les deux avec la même intensité.

> J'aime la physique aussi bien que la chimie.

veut dire que j'aime la physique et la chimie mais ne dit pas si j'aime les deux avec la même intensité. *Aussi bien* est ici synonyme de *et* ou *ainsi que*.

Comment: Alors "aussi bien" veut dire ici la même chose que "ainsi que" ?

Comment: Tout à fait. Je n'ai pas pensé à le dire !

Comment: « Autant que » = *as much as* et « aussi bien que » = *as well as*